# 404 error at REST web project

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, glassfish, jersey

I'm with this test project named `CLAWS-Dicionario`, and I'm trying to run it on Glassfish server (which is working flawlessly). All I have is that class:

```
package com.k19.restful.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET 
    @Produces("text/plain") 
    public String showHelloWorld() { 
        return "Olá mundo!"; 
    }
}
```

And this add at web.xml in order to incorporate Jersey to it

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.k19.restful.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've also added the following jersey libraries to my build-path:

```
asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jersey-server.jar
org.osgi.core-4.2.0
```

So I run the project, and everything feels fine. But when I try to access this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/CLAWS-Dicionario/helloworld
```

It returns a 404 error. I'm sure the host is congured at 8080 port (the URL `localhost:8080` works just fine). So what is the problem?

EDIT: The server began to present another problems, which took me to that line of the `domain.xml` file:

```
 <application context-root="/CLAWS_-_Dicionário" object-type="user" name="CLAWS-Dicionario" directory-deployed="true" location="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/eclipseApps/CLAWS-Dicionario/">
```

Repare the `CLAWS_-_Dicionário` part. Would this be the real name of my project? I had to remove the accent in order the server to work, and I'm finding no more console response when running the project...and even if I try the URL `http://localhost:8080/CLAWS_-_Dicionario/helloworld`, the error is still there,so...just found it something important to point.

Comment: Your project path might be wrong. Check your logs to find out if it is actually CLAWS-Dicionario or just something similar (eg. you named your project "claws", or "demo" or something).

Comment: Where in the log file? Found nothing there very useful. PS: please see the edit.

Comment: From your edit the context root is the path of your application. Try context-root="/CLAWS-Dicionario" and http://localhost:8080/CLAWS-Dicionario/helloworld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which Servlet version you use, you need:

For Servlet 2.x implementation:

- jersey-container-servlet-core.jar

For Servlet 3.x implementation:

- jersey-container-servlet.jar

**org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer** is not packaged in jersey-server.jar

According to the api doc for Class [ServletContainer](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html)

> If the initialization parameter is not present and a initialization
>   parameter "jersey.config.server.provider.packages" is present (see
>   ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES) a new instance of ResourceConfig
>   with this configuration is created. The initialization parameter
>   "jersey.config.server.provider.packages" MUST be set to provide one or
>   more package names. Each package name MUST be separated by ';'.

The parameter `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` have been replaced by `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` in version 2.x.

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.k19.restful.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
```

In `domain.xml`, you should have the `context-root` representing the url path from where the application is accessible:

```
<application context-root="/CLAWS-Dicionario" object-type="user" name="CLAWS-Dicionario" directory-deployed="true" location="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/eclipseApps/CLAWS-Dicionario/">
```

letting you access your application from:

```
 http://localhost:8080/CLAWS-Dicionario/helloworld
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I 'm going to listen some 80 hits to celebrate now!

Comment: Well have fun, It was a pleasure!